# How do you position or float one div next to an absolute div

Tags: html, css

I want a div to appear side-by-side with a google map. However, the google map HAS to be absolute positioned in order for it to take a percentage height.

```
<style>

        #text{
        height:40%;
        width:40%;
        float:left;
        display:inline;
        margin:10px;
        background-color:white;

        }
        #map{
        height:100%;
        width:40%;
        float:left;
        position:absolute;
        }                   
    </style>

        <div id="map1"> </div>
    <div id="infoBox">text goes here </div>
```

Comment: add margin-left: 40%; to #text (append it as the last property)

Comment: Why do you want to float an absolute positioned element? That defeats the purpose of using it. Instead you should use left:0;

Comment: Oh boy, @ProfileTwist, Thanks. That makes sense. Please answer so I can check mark.

doppel I'm not sure, I will try the left:0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are at it just go ahead with:

```
position: absolute;
left: 40%;
```

on the text element. You'll maintain your margin-left of 10px this way.

```
#infoBox{
    height:40%;
    width:40%;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
}
#map{
    height:100%;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22Dhy/

Answer (score 0):

```
#map {
    left: 40%; /* width of #infoBox */
    margin-left:10px; /* greater than or equal to left margin of #infoBox */
}
```